Calculating the derivative of $ I(x) = \int_{x}^{\pi} \bigg( \frac{1 - \cos(y)}{\cos(x) - \cos(y)} \bigg)^{1/2} dy $
Consider the function ${I}\left(x\right)$ defined by the integral
$$
{I}\left(x\right) =
\int_{x}^{\pi}\left[\frac{1 - \cos\left(y\right)}{\cos\left(x\right) - \cos\left(y\right)}\right]^{1/2}
{\rm d}y,\qquad x \in \left[0,\pi\right]
$$

The integral can be calculated exactly using a series of variable substitutions ( e.g. one can set $y = \pi - 2\alpha$, use the double angle formula for the cosine function and then set $u = \sin\left(\alpha\right)$ to calculate it ), and the result is that ${I}\left(x\right) = \pi$ independent of $x$.
Another way to show this result would be to note that $I(0) = \pi$ ( since for $x = 0$ the integrand is just $1$ ) and then show that the derivative of $I$ is zero everywhere.
The latter can of course be done using the same substitutions as mentioned above.

Question. But I would like to know if it is possible to show that ${I}\left(x + \epsilon\right) = {I}\left(x\right) + o\left(\epsilon\right)$ directly without the substitutions ? (Of course we actually have ${I}\left(x+\epsilon\right) = {I}\left(x\right)$, but suppose we don't know that.)

Can you tried it with the $\cos$ in the denominator then using sum expression for the $\cos$ in the integrand, justifying properly that you can make and integrate a certain asymptotic development $\mathcal{O}$ e.g.

I am not sure I can follow you, @EDX. What exactly do you mean by "trying it with the cos in the denominator then using sum expression for the cos in the integrand"?

How would you feel about this approach?

The problem with Leibniz' rule in this case is that it does not apply because the integrand is singular at the left end.

I wrote another solution.

Let
$$F(y)=\int \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos (y)}{\cos (x)-\cos (y)}}\,dy$$ which is
$$F(y)=-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\cos (y)-1} \csc
   \left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \log \left(\sqrt{\cos
   (y)-\cos (x)}+\sqrt{2} \cos
   \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)$$ Assuming $x \in (0,\pi)$
$$F(\pi)= \pi -i \log (1+\cos (x))$$ The problem is more delicate for $F(x)$. But, under the same assumptions, let $y=x+\epsilon^2$ and expand as a series around $\epsilon=0$ and obtain before simplifications
$$F(x+\epsilon^2)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{-\sin (x)} \sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \csc
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \left(2 \log\left(\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+\log(2)\right)+$$
$$2 \epsilon\, \sqrt{\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} +O\left(\epsilon^{3}\right)$$
Assuming again that $x \in (0,\pi)$, this simplify to
$$F(x+\epsilon^2)=-i \log (\cos (x)+1)+2 \epsilon \, \sqrt{\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} +O\left(\epsilon^{3}\right)$$ making
$$\large\color{blue}{F(\pi)-F(x+\epsilon^2)=\pi -2 \epsilon\, \sqrt{\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}+O\left(\epsilon^{3}\right)}$$
Making $\epsilon=0$ gives the expected result.
Edit
We can do the same considering
$$I(k)=\int_{kx}^\pi \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos (y)}{\cos (x)-\cos (y)}}\,dy \quad \quad\text{with} \quad k>1$$ Expanding the result as a series
$$\large\color{blue}{I(k)=\pi -2  \sqrt{x \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\,\,\sqrt{k-1}+O\left((k-1)^{3/2}\right)}$$
Just for the fun, use $x=\frac \pi 3$ and $k=\frac {11}{10}$. The exact result is
$$\pi +\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{4\cos
   \left(\frac{11 \pi }{60}\right) \sqrt{1-2 \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{15}\right)} }{1-2 \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{15}\right)-4 \cos
   ^2\left(\frac{11 \pi }{60}\right)}\right)$$ and the above aapproximation gives
$$\pi -\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi }{15 \sqrt{3}} }$$ The relative error is $0.464$%.
Including the next term of the series which is
$$-\frac{x^{3/2} (\cos (x)+2)}{6 (\cos (x)+1) \sqrt{\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}\,(k-1)^{3/2}$$ the approximation becomes
$$\pi -\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi }{15 \sqrt{3}} }-\sqrt{\frac{\pi ^3}{116640 \sqrt{3}} }$$ which corresponds to a relative error of $0.005$%.
Update
If the tricks with $\epsilon$ or $k$ make problem to any one
$$F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\sin (x)} \sec \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \left(2 \log \left(\cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+\log (2)\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{-\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}$$
$$F(x)=-i\frac{ \sqrt{\sin (x)} \sec \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \left(2 \log \left(\cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+\log (2)\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}=-i \left(2 \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+\log (2)\right)$$
$$F(x)=-i \log \left(2 \cos ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=-i \log (1+\cos (x))$$ and then the result.

Very nice! Your calculation correctly shows that $I(x) = F(\pi) - F(x) = \pi$ for all relevant $x$. However, I am a still somewhat puzzled, for $I(x+\epsilon) - I(x) = ( F(\pi) - F(x+\epsilon) ) - ( F(\pi) - F(x) ) = ( \pi + O(\epsilon^{1/2}) ) - \pi = O(\epsilon^{1/2})$, and this suggests that $I(x)$ cannot be differentiated w.r.t. $x$. What am I missing here?

Another question: How did you come up with that antiderivative?

@MathiasKlahn. Since lazy, for the antiderivative, I used WA and simplified.. I also use the logarithmic representation  of the arctangent when using the tangent half-angle substitution in another integration procedure.

Alright, I see. Do you have an answer to my first question?

@ClaudeLeibovici, When you say expand as a series around epsilon = 0, what does this mean?

@Mangostino. The limit at the lower bound is indeterminate. Then, this is almost L'Hospital rule.

@Mangostino. Answer updated
